# Display error from API request inside laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to display error message for login credential

Response from API:

```
{#291 ▼
  +"error": "invalid_credentials"
  +"error_description": "The user credentials were incorrect."
  +"message": "The user credentials were incorrect."
}
```

Blade HTML:

```
                    @if($errors->any())
                        <ul class="alert alert-danger form-group row">
                          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                               <li >{{ $error }}</li>
                           @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    @endif
```

But i'm getting only error message invalid_credentials.

Now i want the message display on mine blade view.
Can anyone help me to get this done.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `dd($errors->all())` give you in your blade file?

Answer (score 0):

You're only displaying the $`error` variable from your error. If you want to display only message, change your code to something like this:

```
@if($errors->any())
    <ul class="alert alert-danger form-group row">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li >{{ $error->message}}</li>
        @endforeach
     </ul>
@endif
```

Not tested, but should give you desired result.

Comment: Where is `$message` set?

Comment: Whoops, made a typo. Edited it now.

Comment: If i'm trying $message i'm getting: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: message (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

Comment: then i'm getting Trying to get property 'message' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

Comment: Can you do dd($errors->all()) inside your view, as @vivek_23 suggested, and paste the output in your question.

Comment: Here is the output of dd: ```array:3 [▼
  0 => "invalid_credentials"
  1 => "The user credentials were incorrect."
  2 => "The user credentials were incorrect."
]```

Comment: And you said you only get "invalid_credentials" string as your output in your given code?

Comment: did you inspect the element and made sure the other 2 li's arent created or are created and are hidden?

Comment: I have solved this problem by change the code inside the controller: elseif($httpStatus==401) {
            $error = $data->message;
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($error)->withInput();
        }